# Pyspark - set local cores and application name and use UTC as timezone

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a SparkSession using a SparkConf object in order to use two local cores with a proper application name, and use UTC as the timezone. I have also referred to the Pyspark documentation online and have come up with this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJFVM.png)

Could anyone of you let me know if I am heading in the right direction or not? I shall be extremely grateful for all your help as I am trying to learn this new language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set timezone for your spark session you can set below spark configuration also

```
.config('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC') \
.config('spark.driver.extraJavaOptions', '-Duser.timezone=UTC') \
.config('spark.executor.extraJavaOptions', '-Duser.timezone=UTC')
```